# XFCE4 doesn't remember wallpaper settings

Tags: desktop-customization, xfce4, fedora-19

I have a problem.

When I set wallpaper to List, and add couple of wallpapers to it, it works. But after reboot it reverts to blank.

When I go to the settings, it shows then previous setting of blank, and when I choose list, it shows my wallpapers, and when I close, it again sets until reboot.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I moved from GNOME 3. I was searching, if Nautilus doesn't get in the way. But it doesn't, so I'm really pulling my hair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked this bug down along with guys @ Redhat bugtracker, and it turned down to be Wallpapoz ninja-running in the background and messing up wallpaper.